# How to force all tag using style in parent's tag?

Tags: html, css

I have some code html like:

```
<div style=color: green>
  <span style="color:black>Some text</span>
  <p style="color:red>Some text</p>
  <div style="color:blue>Some text</div>
</div>
```

I want all 'Some text' have red follow by it's parent, please help!

Comment: can you not remove the inline style rules from the html?

Comment: all the tags in div tag i can not change so i want to create a div cover them and set color. The answer below has helped me. Thank for comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO Dear

> Use `*` selector with `!important` as you use inline style so
>   `!important` need for override that.

```css
div *{
 color: inherit !important;//parent color you can change it
}
```

```html
<div style="color: green">
  <span style="color:black">Some text</span>
  <p style="color:red">Some text</p>
  <div style="color:blue">Some text</div>
</div>
```

**And also you missed `"` around your styles**

Comment: It might be better to use `color: inherit !important;`, so children will always use parent's color instead of hardcoded color.

Comment: @Volvox But i can not change tags inside

Comment: @Volvox I agreed and Nguyen why you need to change tag? i mean whats the purpose

Answer (score 0):

the best and smart way to make that is creating a class to reuse the code in a future, you can make this

```
.custom-parent > .custom-child{
     color:green !important;
}

<div class="custom-parent">
   <p class="custom-child">some text</p>
   <a href="#" class="custom-child">some text</a>
   <spam class="custom-child">some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the parent div to have a class like `parent`.
From there, I would do.

```css
.parent {
  color: green;
}

.parent * {
  color: inherit !important;
}
```